# Comments in Active admin show page not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, activeadmin, show

I am building an admin site using Active admin in which I have added comments in `user` show page but receives the argument error:

**app/admin/user.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :email
      row :created_at
    end
    active_admin_comments
  end
end
```

**initializers/active_admin.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # == Admin Comments
  #
  # This allows your users to comment on any resource registered with Active Admin.
  #
  # You can completely disable comments:
  # config.comments = false
  #
  # You can change the name under which comments are registered:
  # config.comments_registration_name = 'AdminComment'
  #
  # You can change the order for the comments and you can change the column
  # to be used for ordering:
  # config.comments_order = 'created_at ASC'
  #
  # You can disable the menu item for the comments index page:
  # config.comments_menu = false
  #
  # You can customize the comment menu:
  # config.comments_menu = { parent: 'Admin', priority: 1 }

  # == Pagination
  #
  # Pagination is enabled by default for all resources.
  # You can control the default per page count for all resources here.
  #
  # config.default_per_page = 30
  #
  # You can control the max per page count too.
  #
  # config.max_per_page = 10_000
end
```

**initializers/will_paginate.rb**

```
# Set 'alias_method' for Active admin..
module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    alias_method :total_count, :count
  end
end
```

**Error stack trace :**

```
Rendering /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/will_paginate-3.1.5/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:140:in `select_for_count'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:199:in `perform_calculation'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:121:in `calculate
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record_5.rb:46:in `calculate'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:40:in `count'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/views/active_admin_comments.rb:23:in `title'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/views/active_admin_comments.rb:16:in `build'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `active_admin_comments_for'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/show_page_helper.rb:18:in `active_admin_comments'
    /Users/gokul/Projects/myapp-backend/app/admin/user.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/show.rb:21:in `instance_exec'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/show.rb:21:in `main_content'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in build_main_content_wrapper'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:92:in `block in build_main_content_wrapper'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:91:in `build_main_content_wrapper'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:77:in `block in build_page_content'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:76:in `build_page_content'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:50:in `block in build_page'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:49:in `build_page'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:2:in `block in ___sers_gokul__rvm_gems_ruby_______myapp_gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb__3912673539045957937_70356668255780'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/arbre-1.1.1/lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `new'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `___sers_gokul__rvm_gems_ruby_______myapp_gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb__3912673539045957937_70356668255780'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:104:in `_render_template'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/wicked_pdf-1.1.0/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:42:in `render_with_wicked_pdf'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/wicked_pdf-1.1.0/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:27:in `render'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/responders-2.4.0/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/responders-2.4.0/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:170:in `to_html'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/responders-2.4.0/lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:107:in `to_html'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/responders-2.4.0/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in `respond'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/responders-2.4.0/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/responders-2.4.0/lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:211:in `respond_with'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/inherited_resources-1.7.2/lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:13:in `show'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.2.0.334/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
    /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
      Rendered /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/activeadmin-1.1.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb (330.5ms)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 624ms (ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)



    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `children?' for nil:NilClass):
        1: insert_tag renderer_for(:show)

    activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/components/panel.rb:26:in `children?'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:58:in `append_return_block'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
    activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:92:in `block in build_main_content_wrapper'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
    activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:91:in `build_main_content_wrapper'
activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:77:in `block in build_page_content'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
    activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:76:in `build_page_content'
    activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:50:in `block in build_page'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:49:in `build_page'
    activeadmin (1.1.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (1.1.0) app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:2:in `block in ___sers_gokul__rvm_gems_ruby_______myapp_gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb__3912673539045957937_70356668255780'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
    arbre (1.1.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
activeadmin (1.1.0) app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `new'
    activeadmin (1.1.0) app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb:1:in `___sers_gokul__rvm_gems_ruby_______myapp_gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_show_html_arb__3912673539045957937_70356668255780'
    actionview (5.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
      Rendering /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
      Rendering /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
      Rendered /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (10.5ms)
      Rendering /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
      Rendered /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.5ms)
      Rendering /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
      Rendered /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
      Rendered /Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@myapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (97.7ms)
```

Please help how to fix this issue.

Thanks..

Comment: More stack trace please.

Comment: @PiersC I have added some more stack traces..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `will_paginate` gem from Gemfile. It is no longer required in ActiveAdmin.

Pagination in ActiveAdmin is done with help of the `kaminari` gem.

Comment: But, Iam using will paginate in my app.